# 'jQuery UI Draggable' prevents some clicks on elements inside the draggable container

Tags: android, vue.js, jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building a menu that's draggable horizontally:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgSmi.gif]

The code is pretty straightforward, and the dragging works fine:

```
$draggable.draggable({
   axis: "x",
   distance: 30,
   delay: 40,
   scroll: false
});
```

**Here's the issue at a high level:**

- ***With*** jQuery Draggable:

  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyaZv.gif]

  Every time you see the mouse go from one button to the other, you can assume that I'm clicking. And as you can see, there are some clicks that are ignored/missed (the click callback is not called at all).
- ***Without*** jQuery Draggable

  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2LDK.gif]

  You can see that no clicks are missed (and for some reason, there's this browser blue overlay that doesnt appear when jquery draggable is on, that might be part of the issue)

---

I tried to play with the `distance` and `delay` options of jQuery draggable but it doesn't seem to affect the issue in any way.

I also have a secondary issue that's probably related. On Android 9, on Chrome, you can barely click on the buttons at all. It works when you click on the "padding" part, but not on the text itself, which is REALLY weird to me. On iOS tho, it works fine.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84aYx.png]

---

Here's the mark-up in case it helps:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xByfV.png]

---

Do you have any idea on why jQuery Draggable breaks the clicks on desktop and/or mobile?

Comment: I would first suggest you define a handle. This will help `click` from bubbling for `dragstart`. If you do not want to add a handle, then `distance` might be an issue (version deprecated: 1.12). If the click does not initiate a drag, then it should just get read as a `click` versus `dragstart` event. Otherwise provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: According to the jQuery UI API Documentation, the `Distance` and `Delay` options are deprecated as of version 1.12. Specifically: *(#10615) Interactions should be instantaneous. These settings are typically used to prevent accidental drags, but a proper fix for that is to improve the user experience, e.g., using handles to avoid accidental drags.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I bet a handle would help, but it's not really the expected UI for this kind of menu. Imo users expect to be able to drag it without aiming for a handle. It's unfortunate because it works just fine on some devices.

Yea, I noticed that the 2 options were deprecated, but they're still working (I noticed their effect), and since jUI hasnt been updated in aaages, I would gladly use them if they fixed my issue. 

If I get really desperate, I'll try using a handle, but hopefully someone can help me. Or maybe I can use another drag library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 1.12, I can click and I can drag without `distance`. See the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#pills-container .draggable").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    scroll: false,
    containment: [
      0 - ($(window).width() / 2),
      0,
      $(window).width() + ($(window).width() / 2),
      0
    ]
  });
  $("#pills-container .filter-pill").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
.draggable-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em;
  overflow: none;
}

.draggable-container .filter-pill {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.draggable-container .filter-pill.ui-state-highlight {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="pills-container" class="ui-widget">
    <div class="draggable-container ui-widget-header">
      <div class="draggable">
        <div class="filter-pill mr-4 ui-widget-content">Location</div>
        <div class="filter-pill mr-4 ui-widget-content">Length</div>
        <div class="filter-pill mr-4 ui-widget-content">Interests</div>
        <div class="filter-pill mr-4 ui-widget-content">More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am testing with FireFox 84 (64-bit Linux). If I drag a pill, it does catch the click too.

Comment: Something else in my app must be causing this issue. I'm using the same versions of jq and jqUI, but even when I add this code without Vue.js, it behaves differently.

No matter, what I needed was actually pretty simple, so I implemented a simple horizontal drag myself, that's better integrated with Vue, and everything is working well.

Thanks.